# Using Boost in a DLL project (ActiveX)

Tags: c++, boost, dll, visual-studio-2013, boost-asio

I'm trying to use Boost.Asio on a ActiveX DLL project using Visual Studio 2013. 
Not sure what is wrong but when building these error shows up:

> Error 34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl
>   boost::system::system_category(void)"
>   (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced
>   in function "public: __thiscall
>   boost::system::error_code::error_code(void)"
>   (??0error_code@system@boost@@QAE@XZ)  C:\eCompany\activex-dll\maindoor\RESTClient.obj maindoor
>   Error 35  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl
>   boost::system::generic_category(void)"
>   (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for
>   'errno_ecat''(void)"
>   (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ) C:\Projects\eCompany\activex-dll\maindoor\RESTClient.obj    maindoor
>   Error 36  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved
>   externals C:\Projects\eCompany\activex-dll\maindoor\Debug\maindoorEWI.dll 1   1   maindoor

I already added `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in the Preprocessor. What could be missing in the project?

Comment: Looks like you're not linking to the Boost.System library (Asio has a dependency on that). Why did you add `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`? That disables auto linking. With auto linking you'd probably have been able to link successfully.

Comment: If I remove it, this is the only error: 
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib' not sure why its not in the C:\local\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib folder

Comment: Did you build Boost? If not, open a VS2013 command prompt, and from within your Boost directory run `bootstrap && b2 --build-type=complete stage`. [Here's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html) the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to do something like this:

```
C:\local\boost_1_58_0>bjam.exe runtime-link=static
```

and remove BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB is its set, then build the DLL again. That should fix that.