# Cannot register regsvr32 a DLL with Boost on it

Tags: c++, boost, dll

I'm trying to do `regsvr32` for a ActiveX DLL with Boost on it, so far I can build the DLL just fine.

However the issue is `regsvr32` keeps on failing. A possible workaround can be found here: http://binglongx.com/tag/regsvr32/

If I try to add `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` it gives this error `"Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."` So I remove it so there's no such error. When removed, the DLL can be built just fine.

Now my question is how to be able to regsvr32 a ActiveX DLL with Boost on it? Does anyone have tried it and made it work?

Comment: Rebuild Boost, and this time don't statically link to the runtime, that's a bad idea in most cases anyway (not sure why the person who answered your last question suggested that, it was completely unrelated to your previous problem). Invoke `b2` with `runtime-link=shared` instead of `static`, and then you should be able to use `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`.

Comment: If I use BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK then I should add the boost DLL's on the debug and release folder right? Is this the only solution?

Comment: I get the impression that the conflict is not with Boost's build configuration, but the ActiveX DLL itself seems to be linking against the static runtime library. Make sure it uses the same flags (dynamic runtime!) as the Boost binaries do. (IOW @Praetorian I didn't see anything that suggests that boost was actually compiled with the `runtime-link=static` option as you assume. I think the reverse is more likely).

Comment: Doing what you suggested, its giving "Error 110 error C1189: #error :  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."

Comment: @sehe I assumed the static linking part from the answer to his [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31301128/241631) and the error he saw when trying to dynamically link to Boost. But if dynamic linking to the runtime isn't working either, then I'm out of ideas.